# Ошибка в PHP и JS коде "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: php, javascript, json, php7

На моём сайте такая ошибка в консоли браузера:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

Код JavaScript:

```
unction chatTest() {
      var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
      xmlhttp.open("POST","functionsTest.php",true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send("update=1");
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
      response = JSON.parse(response);
      if (array.length == response.length) return;
      var start = array.length;
      array = response;
      var message = document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML;
      for (i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
      message = message + "<p><b>" + array[i].name + ":</b> " + array[i].message + "</p>"
     }
     document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = message;
     document.getElementById("chat").scrollTop = 1000000;
      }
      }
      }
      setTimeout("chatTest()", 1000);
      }
```

PHP:

```
elseif(isset($_POST["update"])) {
      $string = file_get_contents("messageTest.txt");
     $array = explode("\n", $string);
     $result = array();
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
         $temp = explode(";", $array[$i]);
         $result[$i]["name"] = $temp[0];
         $result[$i]["message"] = $temp[1];

     }
     echo json_encode($result);     }
```

Comment: Я сделаю такую ошибку в 15 символов: `JSON.parse("{")` - кто короче?))

Comment: @Qwertiy, `JSON.parse("")` :)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, `JSON.parse\`\`` :D

Comment: @Qwertiy, а это круто, сдаюсь и ухожу гуглить)

Comment: @VIP300100 что значит _СРОЧНО_? Вы в самом деле рассчитываете на "скорую помощь"? Тогда вы не там её ищете. Подобные поиски следует вести, к примеру, на fl.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно:

1. Кодировка файла utf-8
2. При его сохранении кодировать с флагом `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

   ```
   json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Ты делаешь explode по ";", а в массиве стоит ":"

Comment: Если вы про эту строку 

message = message + "<p><b>" + array[i].name + ":</b> " + array[i].message + "</p>"

то так и должно быть

Answer (score 0):

PHP вывод

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Не помогло ....

Comment: @VIP300100 Попробуйте console.log(response); использовать до конвертации парсинга JSON, а в PHP выводе не ставьте header и не кодируйте вывод в json формате. Что выведет консоль?

Comment: До JSON.parse выводит Array без кодирования , после JSON.parse выводит пустоту

Comment: А если с кодированием то везде выводит пустот